# listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3306 when attempting connection with MySQL server via Node.JS app

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, windows-10, amazon-rds

I am experiencing problems with MySQL connection since making a few changes, and exhausted all suggestions, found here and the net as well as official troubleshooting docs, I come here in the hope of help.

The problem.
When trying to connect to MySQL DB via Node.JS (VSC)

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3306

Node works on all Ports as requested, apart from any port that MySQL uses. Also MySQL connection fails if either the port number is edited or a new instance created.

A little history of the problem:
Worked perfectly with Node.JS app + MySQL DB Workbench 8.0 (MWB). Could connect and webpage populated with data from DB with no issues until i hooked it up to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which I have since delete but problem persists even though I'm back at the beginning.

Comment: The best way to debug problems is to keep them simple. Think what could cause the error you get, and abstract it away from anything else. In your case, the error is caused by Node when trying to boot up the server on the port you assigned to `process.env.PORT`. Port 3306 is the default port used by the MySQL instance. Will leave you deduct the rest :)

Comment: I ale, thanks for your comment. I have tried all manner of Port scripts without success. the simplest I had was: app.listen(3306, ()=>{'...'}

Comment: I was about to write the answer, but I ended up upvoting Mark's answer as that's indeed what you're looking for. Set MySQL port to be `3306`; Node port should instead be `80`, `8080`, or anything else you feel like really. So to fix your error, set your `.env` `PORT` with anything other than `3306`. Same for `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3306;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3306` is the port MySQL listens on. Your NodeJS app should not try to also listen on that port.

You should be specifying port `3306` here:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "root12345",
});
```

Not here:

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`listening to port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

Your app should probably be listing on port `80` or `443` or whatever is appropriate for whatever your NodeJS app is trying to do. It may not need to listen on any port at all.

---

Also, you are using local MySQL here, you aren't making a connection to RDS at all, you are making a connection to the MySQL software running on the same server as the NodeJS app.

Comment: hi Mark, thanks for your comment. Maybe I wasn't explicit enough but I am connected locally and I deleted the AWS RDS as a way of narrowing down the problem.

Comment: @Simon my final comment was just an asside because I noticed you mentioned RDS several times in your question, I didn't read your entire question because it was way too long and went off on too many tangents. The first part of my answer, before the horizontal dividing line,  is the actual "answer" to your question.

Comment: yeah sorry about the overload. I appreciate the help. still not working but will keep trying. Just a question. as everything was working before ie node app was listening on the port my mysql db on. i assumed they needed to be on the same port or channel for data to propagate from server to client?

Comment: They cannot be on the same port. That's not how ports work. Only one service can listen on a specific port, other things send requests to that port.

Comment: I've been lost for days, and yet a simple solution. Thank you Mark (and 
ale917k ). I can now move on to another problem that's surely just around the corner. Take care.......